# Replace part of template with contents of html file in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a problem with replacing part of website built in django with another content.
I have a code like

```
<section id='main_page'>
    <div id="main_div">
        <--! include kek.html content here -->
    </div>
</section>
```

and I'd like to replace this comment with html placed in another html file.
I tried

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string(
            'index.html',{'bla':kek.html},
        ))
```

while in in index.html was

```
<section id='main_page'>
    <div id="main_div">
        {{ bla }}
    </div>
</section>
```

but, it doesn't seem to work that way. I'm kinda new to django and python and I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that wouldn't even run (`kek.html` is not defined in the view, so it's a NameError).

You can use the `{% include %}` tag in the template for this:

```
<section id='main_page'>
    <div id="main_div">
        {% include 'kek.html' %}
    </div>
</section>
```

You should really do the Django tutorial, which explains how templates work (among other things).

**Edit after comment**

In that case you should treat the *name* of the include as a variable and pass it from the view:

```
{% include template_to_include %}
```

...

```
return render_to_response(
        'index.html', {'template_to_include': 'kek.html'},
)
```

Note the quotes.

Comment: I already tried that, it works, but i want to replace that {{ bla }} with different htmls. Your solution will always place kek.html there. For example I want the content to change depending on which button was clicked, so it would just replace {{ bla }} with different html.

Comment: Edited version works great! Thanks, I thought I already tried that way, but I seems I didn't.